# SQL how to filter out values with two decimals

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How do I filter out values for just one decimal place. For example, my column has values VP279.27 and VP 279.27.1
I only want the values for numbers that only have 1 decimal place like VP279.27

How would I do this in SQL? What does my where filter look like?

Comment: You are looking for strings that have exactly one dot in them? `where value like '%.%' and value not like '%.%.%'`.

Comment: Do you have values like `VP 279.27.1.2` or `VP 279.27.1.2.3` too?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `REGEXP` here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col NOT REGEXP '\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+$';
```

### Demo

The logic here is to filter off any record having a column value with 2 (or more) dot separated numbers.  Just a single dot followed by an ending numbers is still allowed.

Comment: Any other way to do this? The above is not returning all the values

Comment: Without seeing your data I can't possibly help you with that.  Reveal the actual data in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the sample data in your question you can use `NOT LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE col NOT LIKE '%.%.%'
```

This will filter out any value that has at least 2 dots.

Comment: tbh this is actually a good answer as per the question

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to use `replace`

```sql
where length(col) - length(replace(col, '.', '')) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match Chinese words, then the 'char_length()' will be better than 'length()'.

```sql
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    `table_name` 
WHERE
    (char_length(`col_name`) - char_length(replace(`col_name`, '.', ''))) = 1;
```

Comment: This is a reply to nayi224's answer? You could have posted this as a comment there. But you are right proposing `CHAR_LENGTH`. Chinese characters or not, this is about the length of a dot in bytes, and it's better to count this as one character than to rely on the dot being represented by exactly one byte in the string.

Comment: Yes,It's. Thank you for reminding! I got his answer, so I thought about it... His answer is not perfect and cannot fit all the characters. Maybe I should reply him under his comment, which is conducive to the classification of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible with:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE col = SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',2);
```

Or maybe, what you really want is not a condition in `WHERE`:

```
SELECT col, SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',2) FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

My take:

```
select *
from yourTable
where col regexp '^[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$';
```

does the job

Demo -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dacd57/1